Issue with MPI Communication in Python (using MPI.COMM_WORLD.isend and MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv) – Receiving None
I'm working on a parallelized program using mpi4py in Python, and I'm encountering an issue where data is being sent using MPI.COMM_WORLD.isend, but when the receiving process attempts to get the data using MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv, it ends up receiving None. I’m unsure if the communication is happening correctly or if there’s an issue with my logic.
Here’s the part of my code where the communication happens:

if self.color == 0:
    current_point = self.run_MD(self.atoms, self.dyn)
    i += 1
    logging.info(f"Sampled point {i}.")    
    for dest in range(1, MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()): 
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.isend(current_point, dest=dest, tag=0)

    if req is None:
        req = MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv(source=1, tag=1)
    
    if req.Test():
        sampled_points = req.wait()
        logging.info(f"Received {sampled_points}.")
        req = None

elif self.color == 1:
    if req is None:
        req = MPI.COMM_WORLD.irecv(source=0, tag=0)
    
    # Get the current point (blocking)
    current_point = req.wait()
    i += 1

    if RANK == 1:
        logging.info(f"Recalculating point {i} with DFT.")  
    sampled_points.append(self.recalc_aims(current_point))

    if RANK == 1:
        logging.info(f'len(sampled_points): {len(sampled_points)}')
        req_send = MPI.COMM_WORLD.isend(sampled_points, dest=0, tag=1)
        req_send.wait()
        req = None


If I don't check using .test(), i.e. using blocking communication, everything works as intended. But somehow, even though .test() evaluates to True, color 0 only receives None for sampled_points. BTW, the communication going in this example from 0 to 1 (sending current_point) works fine.

you have to MPI_Wait() all your requests (inclusing the isend() requests from the very first loop. At first glance you logic looks uncommon and prone to messages being not matched. If you problem persist, trim your code down to a [mcve] and post it.

Your req.wait() cannot see any message, because you already successfully tested for the message in the line above.

@Joachim this is an interesting semantic from mpi4py. is there a way to retrieve the received message after req.Test()? or is the only option (if Test() is to be used) to pass a buffer when invoking irecv()?

@GillesGouaillardet to get the message from test, s, sampled_points = req.test() can be used. Providing a buffer to irecv should also work. An alternative might be to use sampled_points = m.recv() if m=comm.iprobe(source=1, tag=1).

good to know, thanks @Joachim
